# Type error when using todataurl

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Whenever I try to run this, I get a type error in chrome: **Code Update**

```
// Get the drawing canvas
canvas = $('#drawing');
context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');

function resizeCanvas() {

    canvas.attr({'width' : $(window).width()});
    canvas.attr({'height' : $(window).height() - 158});

    var dataURL = canvas[0].toDataURL('image/png');
    context.drawImage(dataURL, 0, 0);

}

$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeCanvas();
}); resizeCanvas();

// Various event handlers after this.
```

Why!?

Comment: Uncaught typeError: type error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drawImage` takes an image or a canvas reference, you are passing it a string.

For instance:

```
var a = document.createElement("canvas");
a.getContext("2d").drawImage("asdasdasd", 0, 0 )
//TypeError: Type error
```

You could try:

```
context.drawImage(canvas[0], 0, 0);
```

Or

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = dataURL;
context.drawImage( image, 0, 0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine. Check the following:

1. There exists a `canvas` element with id `drawing`;
2. Your version of Chrome supports `canvas`.

Comment: Yeah it definitely supports canvas, actually, there is more code relating to the canvas where I bind event handlers to the canvas element, and they all work. It's just this one line throws a type error. The #drawing element exists too!

Comment: What is the exact line that is throwing that error? `getContext`? I've tried your code locally and everything works fine. I've only been able to reproduce that error when a `canvas` element doesn't exist with the given `id`.

Comment: @Johnny you will get this solved quicker when you say what error you get.

Comment: In chrome it literally just says "Uncaught Typeerror: type error" on the line context.drawImage(). I had it working to a certain extent but it was still throwing the error, and I couldn't do anything else when I resized the window (there were a few other things I wanted to do like resize the canvas to fit the window, but this error blocked those from happening)

Comment: I've updated the code in case the problem is some other code interfering which I've missed.